# Read public events with Application access_token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I'm trying to read public events using graphAPI with my Application access_token.

The token works fine, if I debug it in the debug console, it returns that it is the valid access token for my application.

Calling this https://graph.facebook.com/wikipedia/posts?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN it returns the proper data.

When I try to call the following:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=event&q=concert&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN , the data is always empty.

When I try to call that search with a temp access_token provided by the debug tool, I have heaps of data coming back.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on FB API documentation:

Basic Profile Info of a User (ID, Name, Username, Gender)

A User’s Friends and their IDs

Permissions granted by the User to your App

I guess the only way is to use my user access token for this purpose